# Cannot read property 'click' of undefined. slideToggle with each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each, slidetoggle

I'm trying to make simple slideToggle tabs but unfortunately I'm receiving error in console:

> Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

What I find out myself is that, the jQuery is not treating click() as a function if I'm not mistaken.

**My HTML code:**

```
<div class="container">           
         <div id="mineUI" class="pull-right">
                <div class="row">
                        <div id="mineUIbtn" class="col-md-4 text-center">
                                Home
                                <div id="UIcontent">blabla</div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="mineUIbtn" class="col-md-4 text-center">
                                Ok
                                <div id="UIcontent">blabla</div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="mineUIbtn" class="col-md-4 text-center">
                                Rem
                                <div id="UIcontent">blabla</div>
                        </div>
                </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

**My jQuery code:**

```
 var mineUI = function() {
var UIcontent = $("div#mineUI > div.row > div#mineUIbtn > #UIcontent");
var mineUIbtn = $("div#mineUI > div.row > div#mineUIbtn");



UIcontent.each(function(){
    $(this).slideUp("fast");
});

  mineUIbtn.each(function(i){
      var current_item = $(this)[i];
      current_item.click(function(){
          UIcontent.slideToggle("fast");
      });
  });
};
$(document).ready(mineUI);
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: ID of an element must be unique

Answer (score 1):

Inside an .each(), "this" is the single element, not the collection. So "this" is equal to "mineUIbtn[i]". The error message is saying that it can't read the property of an undefined object ($(this)[i] being undefined).

Edit with more code:
You really shouldn't give multiple things the same id. Make a "mineUIbtn" class and a "UIcontent" class. The following code will not work unless you've done that.

```
var mineUI = function() {
    $(".UIcontent").slideUp("fast"); 

    $(".mineUIbtn").click(function(){
       $(this).child().slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
$(document).ready(mineUI);
```

"this" inside the click handler refers to the specific element that has been clicked, not just all of the mineUIbtn. .child() returns all of its direct children. Since there's only one child and it's the UIcontent, you can go ahead and call .slideToggle() on it.

Comment: It worked but now clicking on either Home, Ok or Rem is opening all three UIcontent instead of specific one.

  `mineUIbtn.each(function(i){
  var current_item = $(this);
  current_item.click(function(){
   UIcontent.slideToggle("fast");
  });
 });`

Comment: Yeah, because that's what "UIcontent.slideToggle("fast")" does. It takes the entire UIcontent collection and slides it. I think you should read up on what the each() function does. I'll edit my answer with the code for how to do what you want.